# How to backup SSIS packages and CUBE Projects from Visual Studio 2013.5?

Tags: backup, restore, ssis, ssas, cube

I'm using VisualStudio 2013.5 to develop SSIS, SSDT and SSAS Cubes (multidimensional and tabular model). I would like to ask you is there a possible to backup SSIS packages and SSAS cubes from VisualStudio to disk to be able to transfer particular once to a diferent workstation with VisualStudio and load/restore them there ? Do you know how to do this ?

Comment: Do you work on a local solution and deploy to the server or do you open an online database from within visual studio?

Comment: I work on a local solution and deploy packages to the server.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is then? Why can't you just copy the solution to another workstation?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe there is some kind of backup/restore solution instead of copying files and folder. But thanks anyway!

Comment: There is a backup/restore solution for the deployed cubes/packages,  for the visual studio file based solutions there are many backup strategies just like any file backup strategy

Comment: Could you tell me how to backup/restore deployed cubes and packages ?